# Help with plot script

Tags: plotting

I need to plot this series: `Series[x*E^(-x), {x, 0, 10}]`: along with the actual function: `x*e^-x` on one graph. I used this script but it isn't working:

```
Plot[{x*E^-x,Evaluate[Normal[Series[x*E^(-x), {x, 0, 10}]]]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Your code works just fine.  Also, plot from 0 to 3, not 0 to 10.

Comment: In general, it's good to be explicit about what you mean when you say something is "not working". Is it not giving you the output you expect? Is it giving an empty graph? Is it giving you *nothing*? Is it spitting out an error? Etc. These will help us diagnose the problem. As it is, I copied and pasted your code into my copy of Mathematica, and it worked fine.

Comment: One (semi-advanced) thing: you might want to be plotting `Evaluate[{x*E^-x,Normal[Series[x*E^(-x), {x, 0, 10}]]}]` since currently the `Evaluate` does nothing

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to examine the effect of changing the order of the [`Series`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html)

```
f[x_] = x*E^-x;

Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[
   {f[x], Normal[Series[f[x], {x, 0, n}]]}],
  {x, 0, 5},
  Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> {-0.5, 0.5},
  PlotLegends ->
   Placed[{f[x],
     Inactive[Sum][(-1)^(k - 1)/(k - 1)! x^k, {k, 1, n}]},
    {.2, .2}]],
 {{n, 10, "Series order"}, 1, 15, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]